Get coordinates from folium.plugins.LocateControl
I have following code which adds locate me button on map to autozoom to user's device location.
map = folium.Map()
LocateControl(auto_start=True).add_to(map)
map.save("map.html")

Please advice how can I get coordinates of this location? I think there should be something on click locate me button event.
